# Android - Can't access int from onCreate() method

Tags: android

I have the following `int`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String max = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MAX);
    final int maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max);
```

And i want to access it from here:

```
public void plus1 (View V)
{
    maxInt ++;
}
```

But i get an error, even when not using `final`, When the `int` is inside the class:

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity {
```

I get a crash.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the crash?  It might be caused by an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `int maxInt;` before `onCreate()` but inside **class**

and **change your code**

`final int maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max);`

**to**

```
maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your app crashing because the variable `maxInt` in plus1 is undefined. `maxInt`'s scope is local to `onCreate`. Also `final` variables are like `constant` variables in C. They can only get a value when you initialize them, meaning you can't change their value.

Your maxInt should not be final and should be a global variable:

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity {

    int maxInt;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ...
        maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max);
        ...
    }

    public void plus1 (View V) {
        maxInt ++;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't access `maxInt` in another method is because you created it in onCreate method. Its scope is local to that method so it isn't visible to rest of the class. Moreover, once OnCreate() goes out of scope, `maxInt` will be destroyed and the data stored in it will be lost.

If you want to access an object/variable all over the class, make it `global`.

```
int maxInt;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    maxInt = Integer.parseInt(max);
...
....
}

public void plus1 (View V) {
  .....   
  maxInt ++;
    ..........
}
```